# O que os caracteres \\ significam no parâmetro de uma função em Elixir?

Tags: funções, elixir

Por exemplo:

```
defmodule Math do   
   def add(a \\ 2, b) do
      a + b   
   end 
end
```

O que essas duas barras significam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso significa um valor padrão para o parametro passado, então no exemplo que dado, caso não seja passado nenhum valor para a variável `a` ela por padrão terá um match com o `number` 2:

```
defmodule Math do   
   def add(a \\ 2, b) do
     a + b   
   end 
end
```

Se testarmos a função no `iex`:

```
iex (1)> c("math.ex")

iex (2)> Math.add(1, 8) # add/2, pois estamos fazendo o match de 1 com `a`
9

iex (3)> Math.add(8) # add/1, pois `a` está com match padrão a 2.
10
```

> Referência a pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563884/what-does-the-double-backslash-mean-in-a-function-parameter-in-elixir